# JQuery search JSON by certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have some car data in JSON format and I have two dropdowns, one for the car make and one for the car model. Now what I want to do is, when the user selects the car make, I now need to search that JSON node for the 'models' data and fill in the second select dropdown. So for example, if I select 'Honda' from the first dropdown, it then uses the 'models' from the 'Honda' node and inserts them into my second dropdown.

Currently I have it finding node [1] but I need it to find the node by 'brand'.

Heres what I have:

```js
var carlist = '[{"brand": "Seat","models": ["Alhambra","Altea","Altea XL","Arosa","Cordoba","Cordoba Vario","Exeo","Ibiza","Ibiza ST","Exeo ST","Leon","Leon ST","Inca","Mii","Toledo"]},{"brand": "Renault","models": ["Captur","Clio","Clio Grandtour","Espace","Express","Fluence","Grand Espace","Grand Modus","Grand Scenic","Kadjar","Kangoo","Kangoo Express","Koleos","Laguna","Laguna Grandtour","Latitude","Mascott","Mégane","Mégane CC","Mégane Combi","Mégane Grandtour","Mégane Coupé","Mégane Scénic","Scénic","Talisman","Talisman Grandtour","Thalia","Twingo","Wind","Zoé"]},{"brand": "Peugeot","models": ["1007","107","106","108","2008","205","205 Cabrio","206","206 CC","206 SW","207","207 CC","207 SW","306","307","307 CC","307 SW","308","308 CC","308 SW","309","4007","4008","405","406","407","407 SW","5008","508","508 SW","605","806","607","807","Bipper","RCZ"]},{"brand": "Dacia","models": ["Dokker","Duster","Lodgy","Logan","Logan MCV","Logan Van","Sandero","Solenza"]},{"brand": "Citroën","models": ["Berlingo","C-Crosser","C-Elissée","C-Zero","C1","C2","C3","C3 Picasso","C4","C4 Aircross","C4 Cactus","C4 Coupé","C4 Grand Picasso","C4 Sedan","C5","C5 Break","C5 Tourer","C6","C8","DS3","DS4","DS5","Evasion","Jumper","Jumpy","Saxo","Nemo","Xantia","Xsara"]},{"brand": "Opel","models": ["Agila","Ampera","Antara","Astra","Astra cabrio","Astra caravan","Astra coupé","Calibra","Campo","Cascada","Corsa","Frontera","Insignia","Insignia kombi","Kadett","Meriva","Mokka","Movano","Omega","Signum","Vectra","Vectra Caravan","Vivaro","Vivaro Kombi","Zafira"]},{"brand": "Alfa Romeo","models": ["145","146","147","155","156","156 Sportwagon","159","159 Sportwagon","164","166","4C","Brera","GTV","MiTo","Crosswagon","Spider","GT","Giulietta","Giulia"]},{"brand": "Škoda","models": ["Favorit","Felicia","Citigo","Fabia","Fabia Combi","Fabia Sedan","Felicia Combi","Octavia","Octavia Combi","Roomster","Yeti","Rapid","Rapid Spaceback","Superb","Superb Combi"]},{"brand": "Chevrolet","models": ["Alero","Aveo","Camaro","Captiva","Corvette","Cruze","Cruze SW","Epica","Equinox","Evanda","HHR","Kalos","Lacetti","Lacetti SW","Lumina","Malibu","Matiz","Monte Carlo","Nubira","Orlando","Spark","Suburban","Tacuma","Tahoe","Trax"]},{"brand": "Porsche","models": ["911 Carrera","911 Carrera Cabrio","911 Targa","911 Turbo","924","944","997","Boxster","Cayenne","Cayman","Macan","Panamera"]},{"brand": "Honda","models": ["Accord","Accord Coupé","Accord Tourer","City","Civic","Civic Aerodeck","Civic Coupé","Civic Tourer","Civic Type R","CR-V","CR-X","CR-Z","FR-V","HR-V","Insight","Integra","Jazz","Legend","Prelude"]},{"brand": "Subaru","models": ["BRZ","Forester","Impreza","Impreza Wagon","Justy","Legacy","Legacy Wagon","Legacy Outback","Levorg","Outback","SVX","Tribeca","Tribeca B9","XV"]},{"brand": "Mazda","models": ["121","2","3","323","323 Combi","323 Coupé","323 F","5","6","6 Combi","626","626 Combi","B-Fighter","B2500","BT","CX-3","CX-5","CX-7","CX-9","Demio","MPV","MX-3","MX-5","MX-6","Premacy","RX-7","RX-8","Xedox 6"]},{"brand": "Mitsubishi","models": ["3000 GT","ASX","Carisma","Colt","Colt CC","Eclipse","Fuso canter","Galant","Galant Combi","Grandis","L200","L200 Pick up","L200 Pick up Allrad","L300","Lancer","Lancer Combi","Lancer Evo","Lancer Sportback","Outlander","Pajero","Pajeto Pinin","Pajero Pinin Wagon","Pajero Sport","Pajero Wagon","Space Star"]},{"brand": "Lexus","models": ["CT","GS","GS 300","GX","IS","IS 200","IS 250 C","IS-F","LS","LX","NX","RC F","RX","RX 300","RX 400h","RX 450h","SC 430"]},{"brand": "Toyota","models": ["4-Runner","Auris","Avensis","Avensis Combi","Avensis Van Verso","Aygo","Camry","Carina","Celica","Corolla","Corolla Combi","Corolla sedan","Corolla Verso","FJ Cruiser","GT86","Hiace","Hiace Van","Highlander","Hilux","Land Cruiser","MR2","Paseo","Picnic","Prius","RAV4","Sequoia","Starlet","Supra","Tundra","Urban Cruiser","Verso","Yaris","Yaris Verso"]},{"brand": "BMW","models": ["i3","i8","M3","M4","M5","M6","Rad 1","Rad 1 Cabrio","Rad 1 Coupé","Rad 2","Rad 2 Active Tourer","Rad 2 Coupé","Rad 2 Gran Tourer","Rad 3","Rad 3 Cabrio","Rad 3 Compact","Rad 3 Coupé","Rad 3 GT","Rad 3 Touring","Rad 4","Rad 4 Cabrio","Rad 4 Gran Coupé","Rad 5","Rad 5 GT","Rad 5 Touring","Rad 6","Rad 6 Cabrio","Rad 6 Coupé","Rad 6 Gran Coupé","Rad 7","Rad 8 Coupé","X1","X3","X4","X5","X6","Z3","Z3 Coupé","Z3 Roadster","Z4","Z4 Roadster"]},{"brand": "Volkswagen","models": ["Amarok","Beetle","Bora","Bora Variant","Caddy","Caddy Van","Life","California","Caravelle","CC","Crafter","Crafter Van","Crafter Kombi","CrossTouran","Eos","Fox","Golf","Golf Cabrio","Golf Plus","Golf Sportvan","Golf Variant","Jetta","LT","Lupo","Multivan","New Beetle","New Beetle Cabrio","Passat","Passat Alltrack","Passat CC","Passat Variant","Passat Variant Van","Phaeton","Polo","Polo Van","Polo Variant","Scirocco","Sharan","T4","T4 Caravelle","T4 Multivan","T5","T5 Caravelle","T5 Multivan","T5 Transporter Shuttle","Tiguan","Touareg","Touran"]},{"brand": "Suzuki","models": ["Alto","Baleno","Baleno kombi","Grand Vitara","Grand Vitara XL-7","Ignis","Jimny","Kizashi","Liana","Samurai","Splash","Swift","SX4","SX4 Sedan","Vitara","Wagon R+"]},{"brand": "Mercedes-Benz","models": ["100 D","115","124","126","190","190 D","190 E","200 - 300","200 D","200 E","210 Van","210 kombi","310 Van","310 kombi","230 - 300 CE Coupé","260 - 560 SE","260 - 560 SEL","500 - 600 SEC Coupé","Trieda A","A","A L","AMG GT","Trieda B","Trieda C","C","C Sportcoupé","C T","Citan","CL","CL","CLA","CLC","CLK Cabrio","CLK Coupé","CLS","Trieda E","E","E Cabrio","E Coupé","E T","Trieda G","G Cabrio","GL","GLA","GLC","GLE","GLK","Trieda M","MB 100","Trieda R","Trieda S","S","S Coupé","SL","SLC","SLK","SLR","Sprinter"]},{"brand": "Saab","models": ["9-3","9-3 Cabriolet","9-3 Coupé","9-3 SportCombi","9-5","9-5 SportCombi","900","900 C","900 C Turbo","9000"]},{"brand": "Audi","models": ["100","100 Avant","80","80 Avant","80 Cabrio","90","A1","A2","A3","A3 Cabriolet","A3 Limuzina","A3 Sportback","A4","A4 Allroad","A4 Avant","A4 Cabriolet","A5","A5 Cabriolet","A5 Sportback","A6","A6 Allroad","A6 Avant","A7","A8","A8 Long","Q3","Q5","Q7","R8","RS4 Cabriolet","RS4/RS4 Avant","RS5","RS6 Avant","RS7","S3/S3 Sportback","S4 Cabriolet","S4/S4 Avant","S5/S5 Cabriolet","S6/RS6","S7","S8","SQ5","TT Coupé","TT Roadster","TTS"]},{"brand": "Kia","models": ["Avella","Besta","Carens","Carnival","Cee`d","Cee`d SW","Cerato","K 2500","Magentis","Opirus","Optima","Picanto","Pregio","Pride","Pro Cee`d","Rio","Rio Combi","Rio sedan","Sephia","Shuma","Sorento","Soul","Sportage","Venga"]},{"brand": "Land Rover","models": ["109","Defender","Discovery","Discovery Sport","Freelander","Range Rover","Range Rover Evoque","Range Rover Sport"]},{"brand": "Dodge","models": ["Avenger","Caliber","Challenger","Charger","Grand Caravan","Journey","Magnum","Nitro","RAM","Stealth","Viper"]},{"brand": "Chrysler","models": ["300 C","300 C Touring","300 M","Crossfire","Grand Voyager","LHS","Neon","Pacifica","Plymouth","PT Cruiser","Sebring","Sebring Convertible","Stratus","Stratus Cabrio","Town & Country","Voyager"]},{"brand": "Ford","models": ["Aerostar","B-Max","C-Max","Cortina","Cougar","Edge","Escort","Escort Cabrio","Escort kombi","Explorer","F-150","F-250","Fiesta","Focus","Focus C-Max","Focus CC","Focus kombi","Fusion","Galaxy","Grand C-Max","Ka","Kuga","Maverick","Mondeo","Mondeo Combi","Mustang","Orion","Puma","Ranger","S-Max","Sierra","Street Ka","Tourneo Connect","Tourneo Custom","Transit","Transit","Transit Bus","Transit Connect LWB","Transit Courier","Transit Custom","Transit kombi","Transit Tourneo","Transit Valnik","Transit Van","Transit Van 350","Windstar"]},{"brand": "Hummer","models": ["H2","H3"]},{"brand": "Hyundai","models": ["Accent","Atos","Atos Prime","Coupé","Elantra","Galloper","Genesis","Getz","Grandeur","H 350","H1","H1 Bus","H1 Van","H200","i10","i20","i30","i30 CW","i40","i40 CW","ix20","ix35","ix55","Lantra","Matrix","Santa Fe","Sonata","Terracan","Trajet","Tucson","Veloster"]},{"brand": "Infiniti","models": ["EX","FX","G","G Coupé","M","Q","QX"]},{"brand": "Jaguar","models": ["Daimler","F-Pace","F-Type","S-Type","Sovereign","X-Type","X-type Estate","XE","XF","XJ","XJ12","XJ6","XJ8","XJ8","XJR","XK","XK8 Convertible","XKR","XKR Convertible"]},{"brand": "Jeep","models": ["Cherokee","Commander","Compass","Grand Cherokee","Patriot","Renegade","Wrangler"]},{"brand": "Nissan","models": ["100 NX","200 SX","350 Z","350 Z Roadster","370 Z","Almera","Almera Tino","Cabstar E - T","Cabstar TL2 Valnik","e-NV200","GT-R","Insterstar","Juke","King Cab","Leaf","Maxima","Maxima QX","Micra","Murano","Navara","Note","NP300 Pickup","NV200","NV400","Pathfinder","Patrol","Patrol GR","Pickup","Pixo","Primastar","Primastar Combi","Primera","Primera Combi","Pulsar","Qashqai","Serena","Sunny","Terrano","Tiida","Trade","Vanette Cargo","X-Trail"]},{"brand": "Volvo","models": ["240","340","360","460","850","850 kombi","C30","C70","C70 Cabrio","C70 Coupé","S40","S60","S70","S80","S90","V40","V50","V60","V70","V90","XC60","XC70","XC90"]},{"brand": "Daewoo","models": ["Espero","Kalos","Lacetti","Lanos","Leganza","Lublin","Matiz","Nexia","Nubira","Nubira kombi","Racer","Tacuma","Tico"]},{"brand": "Fiat","models": ["1100","126","500","500L","500X","850","Barchetta","Brava","Cinquecento","Coupé","Croma","Doblo","Doblo Cargo","Doblo Cargo Combi","Ducato","Ducato Van","Ducato Kombi","Ducato Podvozok","Florino","Florino Combi","Freemont","Grande Punto","Idea","Linea","Marea","Marea Weekend","Multipla","Palio Weekend","Panda","Panda Van","Punto","Punto Cabriolet","Punto Evo","Punto Van","Qubo","Scudo","Scudo Van","Scudo Kombi","Sedici","Seicento","Stilo","Stilo Multiwagon","Strada","Talento","Tipo","Ulysse","Uno","X1/9"]},{"brand": "MINI","models": ["Cooper","Cooper Cabrio","Cooper Clubman","Cooper D","Cooper D Clubman","Cooper S","Cooper S Cabrio","Cooper S Clubman","Countryman","Mini One","One D"]},{"brand": "Rover","models": ["200","214","218","25","400","414","416","620","75"]},{"brand": "Smart","models": ["Cabrio","City-Coupé","Compact Pulse","Forfour","Fortwo cabrio","Fortwo coupé","Roadster"]}]';

var carListJson = JSON.parse(carlist);

$.each(carListJson, function(key, value){
$('#car-makes').append('<option>'+value.brand+'</option>');
});

$('#car-makes').on('change', function() {
$.each(carListJson[1].models, function(key, value){
$('#car-model').append('<option>'+value+'</option>');
});
});
```

```css
select { width:90%; margin-bottom:10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="car-makes">
<option value="0">Select a make</option>
</select>

<select id="car-model">
<option value="0">Select a model</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Instead of hard-coded *"1"*, use index of selected `model`. `Array#findIndex` should help.

Comment: ```carListJson[1].models ---> carListJson.findIndex(c=>c. brand===this.value)```

Comment: You can read about Array#findIndex here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can use `find()` to find the item in the JSON where the `brand` option matches the selected brand. From there you can use `map()` to build the `option` elements to append to the DOM. In addition to this you can use the `html()` method to add these so that the models appended from a previous 'Brand' choice are removed from the `select`. Try this:

```
$('#car-makes').on('change', function() {
  let models = carList.find(o => o.brand == this.value).models.map(model => `<option>${model}</option>`);
  models.unshift('<option value="0">Select a model</option>')
  $('#car-model').html(models);
});
```

Here's a full working example. Note that I swapped the variable names of `carlist` and `carListJson` as they were backwards, ie. `carlist` held the JSON and `carListJson` was an array.

```js
var carListJson = '[{"brand": "Seat","models": ["Alhambra","Altea","Altea XL","Arosa","Cordoba","Cordoba Vario","Exeo","Ibiza","Ibiza ST","Exeo ST","Leon","Leon ST","Inca","Mii","Toledo"]},{"brand": "Renault","models": ["Captur","Clio","Clio Grandtour","Espace","Express","Fluence","Grand Espace","Grand Modus","Grand Scenic","Kadjar","Kangoo","Kangoo Express","Koleos","Laguna","Laguna Grandtour","Latitude","Mascott","Mégane","Mégane CC","Mégane Combi","Mégane Grandtour","Mégane Coupé","Mégane Scénic","Scénic","Talisman","Talisman Grandtour","Thalia","Twingo","Wind","Zoé"]},{"brand": "Peugeot","models": ["1007","107","106","108","2008","205","205 Cabrio","206","206 CC","206 SW","207","207 CC","207 SW","306","307","307 CC","307 SW","308","308 CC","308 SW","309","4007","4008","405","406","407","407 SW","5008","508","508 SW","605","806","607","807","Bipper","RCZ"]},{"brand": "Dacia","models": ["Dokker","Duster","Lodgy","Logan","Logan MCV","Logan Van","Sandero","Solenza"]},{"brand": "Citroën","models": ["Berlingo","C-Crosser","C-Elissée","C-Zero","C1","C2","C3","C3 Picasso","C4","C4 Aircross","C4 Cactus","C4 Coupé","C4 Grand Picasso","C4 Sedan","C5","C5 Break","C5 Tourer","C6","C8","DS3","DS4","DS5","Evasion","Jumper","Jumpy","Saxo","Nemo","Xantia","Xsara"]},{"brand": "Opel","models": ["Agila","Ampera","Antara","Astra","Astra cabrio","Astra caravan","Astra coupé","Calibra","Campo","Cascada","Corsa","Frontera","Insignia","Insignia kombi","Kadett","Meriva","Mokka","Movano","Omega","Signum","Vectra","Vectra Caravan","Vivaro","Vivaro Kombi","Zafira"]},{"brand": "Alfa Romeo","models": ["145","146","147","155","156","156 Sportwagon","159","159 Sportwagon","164","166","4C","Brera","GTV","MiTo","Crosswagon","Spider","GT","Giulietta","Giulia"]},{"brand": "Škoda","models": ["Favorit","Felicia","Citigo","Fabia","Fabia Combi","Fabia Sedan","Felicia Combi","Octavia","Octavia Combi","Roomster","Yeti","Rapid","Rapid Spaceback","Superb","Superb Combi"]},{"brand": "Chevrolet","models": ["Alero","Aveo","Camaro","Captiva","Corvette","Cruze","Cruze SW","Epica","Equinox","Evanda","HHR","Kalos","Lacetti","Lacetti SW","Lumina","Malibu","Matiz","Monte Carlo","Nubira","Orlando","Spark","Suburban","Tacuma","Tahoe","Trax"]},{"brand": "Porsche","models": ["911 Carrera","911 Carrera Cabrio","911 Targa","911 Turbo","924","944","997","Boxster","Cayenne","Cayman","Macan","Panamera"]},{"brand": "Honda","models": ["Accord","Accord Coupé","Accord Tourer","City","Civic","Civic Aerodeck","Civic Coupé","Civic Tourer","Civic Type R","CR-V","CR-X","CR-Z","FR-V","HR-V","Insight","Integra","Jazz","Legend","Prelude"]},{"brand": "Subaru","models": ["BRZ","Forester","Impreza","Impreza Wagon","Justy","Legacy","Legacy Wagon","Legacy Outback","Levorg","Outback","SVX","Tribeca","Tribeca B9","XV"]},{"brand": "Mazda","models": ["121","2","3","323","323 Combi","323 Coupé","323 F","5","6","6 Combi","626","626 Combi","B-Fighter","B2500","BT","CX-3","CX-5","CX-7","CX-9","Demio","MPV","MX-3","MX-5","MX-6","Premacy","RX-7","RX-8","Xedox 6"]},{"brand": "Mitsubishi","models": ["3000 GT","ASX","Carisma","Colt","Colt CC","Eclipse","Fuso canter","Galant","Galant Combi","Grandis","L200","L200 Pick up","L200 Pick up Allrad","L300","Lancer","Lancer Combi","Lancer Evo","Lancer Sportback","Outlander","Pajero","Pajeto Pinin","Pajero Pinin Wagon","Pajero Sport","Pajero Wagon","Space Star"]},{"brand": "Lexus","models": ["CT","GS","GS 300","GX","IS","IS 200","IS 250 C","IS-F","LS","LX","NX","RC F","RX","RX 300","RX 400h","RX 450h","SC 430"]},{"brand": "Toyota","models": ["4-Runner","Auris","Avensis","Avensis Combi","Avensis Van Verso","Aygo","Camry","Carina","Celica","Corolla","Corolla Combi","Corolla sedan","Corolla Verso","FJ Cruiser","GT86","Hiace","Hiace Van","Highlander","Hilux","Land Cruiser","MR2","Paseo","Picnic","Prius","RAV4","Sequoia","Starlet","Supra","Tundra","Urban Cruiser","Verso","Yaris","Yaris Verso"]},{"brand": "BMW","models": ["i3","i8","M3","M4","M5","M6","Rad 1","Rad 1 Cabrio","Rad 1 Coupé","Rad 2","Rad 2 Active Tourer","Rad 2 Coupé","Rad 2 Gran Tourer","Rad 3","Rad 3 Cabrio","Rad 3 Compact","Rad 3 Coupé","Rad 3 GT","Rad 3 Touring","Rad 4","Rad 4 Cabrio","Rad 4 Gran Coupé","Rad 5","Rad 5 GT","Rad 5 Touring","Rad 6","Rad 6 Cabrio","Rad 6 Coupé","Rad 6 Gran Coupé","Rad 7","Rad 8 Coupé","X1","X3","X4","X5","X6","Z3","Z3 Coupé","Z3 Roadster","Z4","Z4 Roadster"]},{"brand": "Volkswagen","models": ["Amarok","Beetle","Bora","Bora Variant","Caddy","Caddy Van","Life","California","Caravelle","CC","Crafter","Crafter Van","Crafter Kombi","CrossTouran","Eos","Fox","Golf","Golf Cabrio","Golf Plus","Golf Sportvan","Golf Variant","Jetta","LT","Lupo","Multivan","New Beetle","New Beetle Cabrio","Passat","Passat Alltrack","Passat CC","Passat Variant","Passat Variant Van","Phaeton","Polo","Polo Van","Polo Variant","Scirocco","Sharan","T4","T4 Caravelle","T4 Multivan","T5","T5 Caravelle","T5 Multivan","T5 Transporter Shuttle","Tiguan","Touareg","Touran"]},{"brand": "Suzuki","models": ["Alto","Baleno","Baleno kombi","Grand Vitara","Grand Vitara XL-7","Ignis","Jimny","Kizashi","Liana","Samurai","Splash","Swift","SX4","SX4 Sedan","Vitara","Wagon R+"]},{"brand": "Mercedes-Benz","models": ["100 D","115","124","126","190","190 D","190 E","200 - 300","200 D","200 E","210 Van","210 kombi","310 Van","310 kombi","230 - 300 CE Coupé","260 - 560 SE","260 - 560 SEL","500 - 600 SEC Coupé","Trieda A","A","A L","AMG GT","Trieda B","Trieda C","C","C Sportcoupé","C T","Citan","CL","CL","CLA","CLC","CLK Cabrio","CLK Coupé","CLS","Trieda E","E","E Cabrio","E Coupé","E T","Trieda G","G Cabrio","GL","GLA","GLC","GLE","GLK","Trieda M","MB 100","Trieda R","Trieda S","S","S Coupé","SL","SLC","SLK","SLR","Sprinter"]},{"brand": "Saab","models": ["9-3","9-3 Cabriolet","9-3 Coupé","9-3 SportCombi","9-5","9-5 SportCombi","900","900 C","900 C Turbo","9000"]},{"brand": "Audi","models": ["100","100 Avant","80","80 Avant","80 Cabrio","90","A1","A2","A3","A3 Cabriolet","A3 Limuzina","A3 Sportback","A4","A4 Allroad","A4 Avant","A4 Cabriolet","A5","A5 Cabriolet","A5 Sportback","A6","A6 Allroad","A6 Avant","A7","A8","A8 Long","Q3","Q5","Q7","R8","RS4 Cabriolet","RS4/RS4 Avant","RS5","RS6 Avant","RS7","S3/S3 Sportback","S4 Cabriolet","S4/S4 Avant","S5/S5 Cabriolet","S6/RS6","S7","S8","SQ5","TT Coupé","TT Roadster","TTS"]},{"brand": "Kia","models": ["Avella","Besta","Carens","Carnival","Cee`d","Cee`d SW","Cerato","K 2500","Magentis","Opirus","Optima","Picanto","Pregio","Pride","Pro Cee`d","Rio","Rio Combi","Rio sedan","Sephia","Shuma","Sorento","Soul","Sportage","Venga"]},{"brand": "Land Rover","models": ["109","Defender","Discovery","Discovery Sport","Freelander","Range Rover","Range Rover Evoque","Range Rover Sport"]},{"brand": "Dodge","models": ["Avenger","Caliber","Challenger","Charger","Grand Caravan","Journey","Magnum","Nitro","RAM","Stealth","Viper"]},{"brand": "Chrysler","models": ["300 C","300 C Touring","300 M","Crossfire","Grand Voyager","LHS","Neon","Pacifica","Plymouth","PT Cruiser","Sebring","Sebring Convertible","Stratus","Stratus Cabrio","Town & Country","Voyager"]},{"brand": "Ford","models": ["Aerostar","B-Max","C-Max","Cortina","Cougar","Edge","Escort","Escort Cabrio","Escort kombi","Explorer","F-150","F-250","Fiesta","Focus","Focus C-Max","Focus CC","Focus kombi","Fusion","Galaxy","Grand C-Max","Ka","Kuga","Maverick","Mondeo","Mondeo Combi","Mustang","Orion","Puma","Ranger","S-Max","Sierra","Street Ka","Tourneo Connect","Tourneo Custom","Transit","Transit","Transit Bus","Transit Connect LWB","Transit Courier","Transit Custom","Transit kombi","Transit Tourneo","Transit Valnik","Transit Van","Transit Van 350","Windstar"]},{"brand": "Hummer","models": ["H2","H3"]},{"brand": "Hyundai","models": ["Accent","Atos","Atos Prime","Coupé","Elantra","Galloper","Genesis","Getz","Grandeur","H 350","H1","H1 Bus","H1 Van","H200","i10","i20","i30","i30 CW","i40","i40 CW","ix20","ix35","ix55","Lantra","Matrix","Santa Fe","Sonata","Terracan","Trajet","Tucson","Veloster"]},{"brand": "Infiniti","models": ["EX","FX","G","G Coupé","M","Q","QX"]},{"brand": "Jaguar","models": ["Daimler","F-Pace","F-Type","S-Type","Sovereign","X-Type","X-type Estate","XE","XF","XJ","XJ12","XJ6","XJ8","XJ8","XJR","XK","XK8 Convertible","XKR","XKR Convertible"]},{"brand": "Jeep","models": ["Cherokee","Commander","Compass","Grand Cherokee","Patriot","Renegade","Wrangler"]},{"brand": "Nissan","models": ["100 NX","200 SX","350 Z","350 Z Roadster","370 Z","Almera","Almera Tino","Cabstar E - T","Cabstar TL2 Valnik","e-NV200","GT-R","Insterstar","Juke","King Cab","Leaf","Maxima","Maxima QX","Micra","Murano","Navara","Note","NP300 Pickup","NV200","NV400","Pathfinder","Patrol","Patrol GR","Pickup","Pixo","Primastar","Primastar Combi","Primera","Primera Combi","Pulsar","Qashqai","Serena","Sunny","Terrano","Tiida","Trade","Vanette Cargo","X-Trail"]},{"brand": "Volvo","models": ["240","340","360","460","850","850 kombi","C30","C70","C70 Cabrio","C70 Coupé","S40","S60","S70","S80","S90","V40","V50","V60","V70","V90","XC60","XC70","XC90"]},{"brand": "Daewoo","models": ["Espero","Kalos","Lacetti","Lanos","Leganza","Lublin","Matiz","Nexia","Nubira","Nubira kombi","Racer","Tacuma","Tico"]},{"brand": "Fiat","models": ["1100","126","500","500L","500X","850","Barchetta","Brava","Cinquecento","Coupé","Croma","Doblo","Doblo Cargo","Doblo Cargo Combi","Ducato","Ducato Van","Ducato Kombi","Ducato Podvozok","Florino","Florino Combi","Freemont","Grande Punto","Idea","Linea","Marea","Marea Weekend","Multipla","Palio Weekend","Panda","Panda Van","Punto","Punto Cabriolet","Punto Evo","Punto Van","Qubo","Scudo","Scudo Van","Scudo Kombi","Sedici","Seicento","Stilo","Stilo Multiwagon","Strada","Talento","Tipo","Ulysse","Uno","X1/9"]},{"brand": "MINI","models": ["Cooper","Cooper Cabrio","Cooper Clubman","Cooper D","Cooper D Clubman","Cooper S","Cooper S Cabrio","Cooper S Clubman","Countryman","Mini One","One D"]},{"brand": "Rover","models": ["200","214","218","25","400","414","416","620","75"]},{"brand": "Smart","models": ["Cabrio","City-Coupé","Compact Pulse","Forfour","Fortwo cabrio","Fortwo coupé","Roadster"]}]';
var carList = JSON.parse(carListJson);

let makes = carList.map(o => `<option>${o.brand}</option>`);
$('#car-makes').append(makes);

$('#car-makes').on('change', function() {
  let models = carList.find(o => o.brand == this.value).models.map(model => `<option>${model}</option>`);
  models.unshift('<option value="0">Select a model</option>')
  $('#car-model').html(models);
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="car-makes">
  <option value="0">Select a make</option>
</select>

<select id="car-model">
  <option value="0">Select a model</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Use [`.find(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `.filter(...)[0]`. `find` is faster, it stops iterating after finding a match. `find(...)` also reads better than `filter(...)[0]`

Comment: @3limin4t0r that is very true, thanks. Not sure why I used `filter()` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the carlist and check each item for the matching brand.

When you find it, interrupt the loop and return the model.

```js
// Your carlist
var carlist = [
  { brand: 'Seat', 'model': ['Ibiza','Mallorca'] },
  { brand: 'Opel', 'model': ['Focus','Astral'  ] }
];

// Your selected brand
var brand = 'Opel';

// Your matching model
var model = (function () {
  // Loop the carlist
  for (var i = 0; i < carlist.length; i++)
    // Check if it is the required brand
    if (carlist[i]['brand'] === brand)
      // Return the model (and interrupt further looping)
      return carlist[i]['model'];
})();
```

NOTE: This is an ECMAScript 5 compatible solution. This can be written easier in ES6, but you might not have the required browser support.